# How to Convert Italian System Long Date To indian integer date

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have below c# code

```
relDTO.StartDate = this.txtRelStartDate.Text.Trim() == string.Empty ? string.Empty : System.Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtRelStartDate.Text).ToShortDateString();
relDTO.EndDate = this.txtRelEndDate.Text.Trim() == string.Empty ?string.Empty : System.Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtRelEndDate.Text).ToShortDateString();
```

and it is returning:

```
relDTO.StartDate= venerdì ‎6 ‎marzo ‎2015

relDTO.EndDate = venerdì ‎6 ‎marzo ‎2015
```

This same date string  I am passing to a stored procedure where I want to convert it as  `Friday, ‎March ‎06, ‎2015` format.

I am expecting some sql function / statement.
Kindly help. TIA.

Comment: This might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What is the (exact) contents of `this.txtRelStartDate.Text`?

Comment: venerdì ‎6 ‎marzo ‎2015

(Long date in italian format)

Comment: Ideally, if you're working with multiple cultures and locations, keep the data in the database as `datetime` data in the UTC timezone, and only deal with *formatting* issues when you actually display it to the users.